# How do you create two lines of images in html/css that slide with the scrolling button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like this -->>(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3QTV.png)

tried didnt work i tried

Answer (score 1):

You need not only html and css but a little bit js. Very simple scroll you can make in 2 minutes:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const left = document.querySelector(".left");
const right = document.querySelector(".right");

left.addEventListener("click", () => {
  wrapper.scrollBy({ left: -100, behavior: "smooth" });
});

right.addEventListener("click", () => {
  wrapper.scrollBy({ left: 100, behavior: "smooth" });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.image-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1500px;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image-group">
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
      <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=300&height=300" />
  </div>
</div>

<button class="left">left</button>
<button class="right">right</button>
```

Or for some advanced variants you can use ready-made solutions
https://freefrontend.com/javascript-carousels/